# ic_launcher_background

Tags: android, android-drawable

Заметил, что в папке `drawable` появились два `xml` файла : `ic_launcher_background` и `ic_launcher_background(v24)`. Так же в папке `values` появился `xml` файл `ic_launcher_background`. Что это такое и с чем связано появление этого файла ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего вы создали проект для версии `API` >= 26 (Android 8.0 Oreo) и с помощью `Android Studio` не менее чем 3.0 версии. С такими условиями в вашем проекте могут быть использованы [адаптивные иконки](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) по умолчанию. Если коротко файл `ic_launcher_background` в `drawable` это слой иконки, в данном случае фона, который представляет собой `VectorDrawable`. В свою очередь файл `ic_launcher_background` с папки `values` скорее всего хранит используемые ресурсы фона, такие как цвет для примера. Больше информации можете узнать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).

Comment: Для проекта минимальное Api 15 стоит

Comment: @Programmer, вам нужно что бы в целевых версиях была указана 26 и выше Android API. Минимальная версия в данном случае не сколько важна.

Comment: Я просто начинающий разработчик под android,и поэтому для проекта выбрал самый минимальный. В дальнейшем какой Api лучше выставлять для проектов - где процент использования будет 80-90% ?

Comment: @Programmer, это уже другой вопрос. Покрыть большую часть пользователей это заманчиво но не забывайте об обратной совместимости. Но это выходит за рамки данного вопроса я же в свою очередь указал условия при которых студия сгенерит по умолчанию адаптивные иконки.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо за помощь.